# How to Solve a Linear Programming Problem in $n$ Dimension Space?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

### Problem

\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize}  & c^T x \\
\text{subject to}& d^T x = \alpha \\
&0 \le x \le 1.
\end{array}

The variable is $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$, $\alpha$ and the components of $d$ are positive.

### What I Have Done

I do not have many tools available to solve this problem since I have just taken the Linear Programming course for a week and only a bunch of concepts have been introduced.

The only two things I think I could use are:

1. Geometry. Visualize the constraints as a hyperplane and a $n$ dimensional cube and do something...
2. Algebra. I tried to solve this problem with certain "magic" inequalities. From the form of object function I thought of [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality), but I do not know how to merge the constraints into this inequality.

P.S. Maybe I miss something and complicate the problem without realizing this since I think this should be a conceptually simple question.

Could anyone help me and give me some hints, thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: what happens if $n=1$? And if $n=2$?

Comment: @Kuifje I have thought about the $n=1,2$ and 3 cases before posting this question. Suppose the feasible set is not empty, then when $n=1$ only a specific point could be taken, when $n=2$ and 3, one of $x_i$ could take 1 and others could not. It seems that I could then pick points in the feasible set such that the object function could be maximized. However, I do not think I could generalize this thinking into $n$ dimensional space with only "observations" and I do not have a formal way to formulate my thoughts. So could you provide more details?

Comment: An intuitive solution to this problem can be found at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607020/how-to-solve-a-linear-programming-problem-without-any-given-data/2607135

Comment: The feasible region is a polyhedron. It is a well-known fact that linear objective functions on polyhedra obtain their maximum in (at least) a vertex of the polyhedron. The vertices of your feasible region are points with only corrdinates zero or one, except one coordinate which must be determines via the plane equation $d^\top x=\alpha$.

Comment: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing
[$\rm \LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), because [pictures may not be legible](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189),
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.
Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: You need to look up the simplex algorithm somewhere. You make the right matrix, and then you can row reduce yourself to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hints to solve this / find a algorithm to solve it:

Let $S = \{x | d^Tx = a , x_i \in [0,1]\}$

- if $a,b \in S$ then $(at + (1-t)b)\in S \forall t\in[0,1]$,
- $ diff(x,y) =c^Ty - c^Tx = c^T(y-x)$